# How to view view.xml file in debugger?

Tags: sapui5

I am running my project locally, where I can see view.xml file and can debug it using breakpoint.

However, when I try to open same file in debugger in my online system, it does not show me this file. Is there any way I can access this file, same way I can locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are 2 ways you can access all the files of project.

1) put this tag in your URL, and reload the page **sap-ui-debug=true**. This will access all the files inside your project.
Like ***fiorilaunchpad.html?sap-client=100&sap-ui-debug=true***

2)

- Press **CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+P**. This will open **Technical Information Dialog** box. There, tick "Use Debug Sources"[image]
- When Prompted, press OK

[image: 2]]

**Step 2 will make app loading slower since it try to access all the resources inside the project.**

Comment: I did not understood step 1. Where should I put this tag?

Comment: In URL of your app. Something similar to what I have updated in my answer.